# Definition for rule 'import/no-cycle' was not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, eslint

I deleted my npm package and package.lock.json file, then I ran npm install and then npm update. So when I started my app using npm run start, I am getting an error

This is the error that is displaying on the screen when I start my app:

[eslint]
src\components\index.jsx
Line 4:1:  Definition for rule 'import/no-cycle' was not found  import/no-cycle

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation for this error would be if your ESLint config enables `'import/no-cycle'`, but does not actually include the `plugin:import` to pull in the `eslint-plugin-import` package.

Check that:

- Your package.json includes a reasonably up to date version of `eslint-plugin-import`
- Your eslint config file (e.g. `eslint-config.js` or `.eslintrc`) doesn't include the `import` plugin: there should be something similar to this:

```js
module.exports = { // or export, or it might be JSON
  // ...various settings
  extends: [
    // ...various plugins
    'plugin:import/recommended', 
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
```

Comment: After add this plugin start working

"extends": [
     "plugin:import/typescript"
],

See https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2895